# Highstock- show full data sets on x axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem. I tried adding two or more data sets to show on highcharts and it's working. But if I change the library to highstock I have a problem, because the gap between data is removed. How can I set the gap for a highstock chart?

[image]

[image]

Now highstock and highcharts are working  with the same data set, but I want to have highstock with a gap (the same as highcharts).

Comment: If you have any further question, please point that out in the comment or create a new question. Don't add it as an answer - it's very misleading for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that disabling `xAxis.ordinal` should solve your problem.

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, it worked. I have the last question, why now I have here line between data. If I try zoom view line is hidden

[picture what's wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvJkM.png)